# Extracting data from nested dictionary JSON file

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to access the keys of first dictionary, and the color `red` only from the list to put them in multidimensional array.

```json
{
  "100": {
     "pass": "edrsf45tf"
     "colors": ["red", "blue"]
  },
  "101": {
     "pass": "trf56trt"
     "colors": ["red", "black", "white"]
  }
}
```

```py
y_train = []

with open('/data.json') as data:
    accessData = json.load(data)
    for i in range(len(accessData)):
        y_train.append(acessData[i]['colors']
```

I'm stuck here, with this desired output:

```
id    color
100   red
101   red
102   null 
...   ...
300   red
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you load the JSON and save it to a dictionary, you can go like this if red color is the first in the colors key:

```
jdct = { "100": { "pass": "edrsf45tf", "colors" :["red", "blue" ] }, 
    "101": { "pass": "trf56trt", "colors": ["red", "black", "white" ] } }
for k,v in jdct.items():
    print(k, v["colors"][0])
```

Comment: error list index out of range

Comment: So your dictionary colors is empty, you could check if it has vale or not if len(v[‘colors’])